# How can i get the div text?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a classroom seats with my HTML and PHP (`only loop`). Here is My Script

```
        <?php for($x=1;$x<41;$x++){?>
                <div class="kolom col-md-3">
                    <div class="headerval"><center><?=$x;?></center></div>
                        <div class="left foo col-md-6">1</div>
                                <div class="right foo col-md-6">2</div>
                        </div> 
                    <?php } ?>  
                </div>
```

and here is the result

[image]

Now, I'm trying to alert the text inside the div `.headerval`. Then I add this JS

```
   $( function() {
        $(document).on("click", ".left", function() {
                 alert($( this ).closest('.headerval').text());
             });    
        $(document).on("click", ".right", function() {
                 alert($( this ).closest('.headerval').text());
             });
  } );
```

with My JS i only able to see empty alert. I have change `closest` to `find` but no help.

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `.headerval` is a sibling not a parent to `.left`.

```
alert($(this).siblings('.headerval').text());
```

As an alternate to `.siblings(` you could use `.prev(` also,

```
alert($(this).prev('.headerval').text());
```

And for the `.right` you have to use,

```
alert($(this).parent().prev('.headerval').text());
```

---

But commonly you can target a parent for the both `.right` and `.left` to simplify your code.

```
 $( function() {
   $(document).on("click", ".left, .right", function() {
       alert($(this).closest('.kolom').find(".headerval").text());
   });    
 });
```

Comment: You made my day. The latest script is a nice tips. But I still need the `.left` or `.right`

Comment: @YVS1102 I don't understand. You want it to be two different events?

Comment: `.left` has 1 and `.right` has 2. so. Why i want to keep two events because i want when i click `.left` i can get two text `.left` and `.headerval`. Ahh sorry for my english

Comment: @YVS1102 Then you can write like, `$(document).on("click", ".left", function() {
       alert($(this).closest('.kolom').find(".headerval").text());
   });` for two times with left and right selector.

Comment: ahh. i can do this `var clicked  = $(this).text();
    var headertext = $(this).closest('.kolom').find(".headerval").text();
       alert(clicked + headertext);`. thankssssss !